# Webpack collecting wrong src path

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I think that the whole problem is in configuring the webpack, the images are successfully collected in the folder when building, but when importing ...

Somewhere I found a solution indicating the public path, but somehow it did not grow together

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
// const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/lib/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "@compassplus/ui-mobicash"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use:  [  
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  url: true,
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            },
        ],
        include: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
            'css-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash:12].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'index.css',
    }),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //     template: './public/index.html',
    // }),
    // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    //     "React": "react",
    //   }),
  ],
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
}
```

Путь указанный в `src` / Path in the `src`:

```
src="images/809853c38dec.svg"
```

In the React component, I hook it up via import and pass it as an object

```
import imgLight from './img/theme-light.svg';
<img src={img} alt='Картинка' className={style.img}></img>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using url-loader:

```
{
    loader: "url-loader",
    options: {
        limit: 8192,
        name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
     },
 }
```

Comment: Could you, please, make your answer a bit more explanatory? What was the cause of the problem, where have you inserted the snippet, and why does it solve the issue?

Comment: Oh sure. I am creating a UI component library and am facing the problem of reusing components where url() or src is used in components.

Comment: By default, React puts all images in the /static/media path, in my config I use a file loader, which puts all my components in the path (/images/[name].[ext]), and, accordingly, url(/images/[name].[ext])

Comment: and in React it should be (/static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]). This is where the whole mistake arose.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to replace the downloader file with a downloader url. I personally cannot tell anything detailed about url-loader. It works like file-loader, however it returns a DataURL, which helped me avoid problems with /static/media.

Comment: @Palo, I hope it became at least a little clearer for you

Comment: Just changing the path when using file-loader to /static/media will not help, React will make its own assembly anyway and it will differ from the given path (it will throw its hash on top)

Comment: Would you be so kind and edit your answer instead of placing this info into multiple comments? I cannot do it because the edit ques are full.